# how to create custom keyboard in telegram .net api?

Tags: .net, telegram-bot

```
if (update.Message.Text == "/hi" || update.Message.Text == "hi")
{
    bot.MakeRequestAsync(new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "TEST!")).Wait();
}
```

telegram api for .net have type of keyboardmuckup  but never  user in any example i see it. can i implement custom keyboard in telegram bot api to get command from user from button instead command text .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes. You never see `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` in codes but in telegram bot [documnetation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup). If you look at this documentation, you see many parts( for example `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` and each part have some `Field`. you must send those fields( specially those `Required` fields) with their value, Telegram would recognize that those fields without mentioning titel(title is for example `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`) you must not mention these titles in your code.
you can see a working keyborad in php [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37948952/6478645).
Every thing is simple as sending a message, the main point in keybords is to use triple arrays nested in each other

```
pseudo code:
keyboard = [[ [key element 1 data] , [key element 2 data] ,[key element 3 data] ]]
```

Comment: implement in .net a little complicated to generate dynamic keyboard per request . please tell me about  set text and value in my replykeyboardmarkup . my cretaed keyboard return text only i want to return value

Comment: you yourself, should parse the texts,  for example in a `switch case` loop.And yourself should convert the text for other types for example `integer`.

Answer (score -1):

in c# you can do this:

```
    using NetTelegramBotApi.Types;
    enter code here

   ReplyKeyboardMarkup myKeyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
  {
      Keyboard = new string[][]
      {
         new string[] { "raw1 key1", "raw1 key2","raw1 key3 " },
         new string[] { "raw2 key1", "raw2 key2","raw2 key3 " }

      }
  };
```

first array of string shows in first raw and second array shows in second raw ...
and you can send this key board to user via sendMessage:

```
var req =new SendMessage(chatId,"Text if you want") { ReplyMarkup = myKeyboard };

await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
```